# Import redis database to python. Migrate db from redis to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, redis, migration, database-migration, data-migration

I have a .rdb file (redis database file). How to import it to python for data analysis?
Also, how to migrate my database from redis to mongodb?

Tried using "rdb --command json dump.rdb" to connect rdb server to the database file I have and then access it in py and convert it into json and then json to mongodb but got this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main  
    `return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run\_code  
    `exec(code, run_globals)`  
  File "user\miniconda3\Scripts\rdb.exe\\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\cli\rdb.py", line 106, in main  
    `parser.parse(options.dump_file[0])`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\parser.py", line 394, in parse  
    `self.parse_fd(open(filename, "rb"))`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\parser.py", line 448, in parse_fd  
    `self.read_module(f)`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\parser.py", line 846, in read_module  
    `record_buffer = self._callback.start_module(self._key, self._decode_module_id(length), self._expiry, info={'idle':self._idle, 'freq':self._freq})`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\callbacks.py", line 130, in start_module  
    `self._out.write(self.encode_key(key) + b':{')`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\callbacks.py", line 22, in encode_key  
    `key = encodehelpers.bytes_to_unicode(key, self._escape, skip_printable=True)`  
  File "user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rdbtools\encodehelpers.py", line 110, in bytes_to_unicode  
    `assert (isinstance(byte_data, type(b'')))`  
AssertionError  
[
```

Regarding `redis` to `mongodb` database migration, since `redis` is a key value pair db and `mongo` is a document based db, there is no way to directly migrate I guess and I wasn't able to find any other way like `redis` to something and that something to `mongo`.

Any solution to any of the two problems above?